# C#/MVC4 : Best pratice for Map linked contents

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have many MVC projects in my solution and i have lots common contents.

First (and best for me) solution: link files from the library/common project (Add as Link).

Second solution: manually copy each files (or with compilation command for each MVC projects).

For the first solution, i have a problem, IIS can't find file, because is in /bin/scripts/file.js and not /scripts/file.js.

I want to map url 'scripts/file.js' ou 'scripts/../../file.js' to good path.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Scripts",
                        url: "js/{filename}.js",
                        defaults: new { controller = "FileLinker", action = "Javascripts", filename = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );
```

The map doesn't work, but when i remove the '.js' it work! But if the request url is 'Scripts/Popup/PopupBase.js', it doesn't work and i must add new routes for 'Scripts/Folder/file.js'. (Same for example : '/Scripts/Popup/Rounded/Popup.js' => new map definition !)

I would like to know the best practice to use ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new web site or application to host all the shared content, and reference its virtual directory name in all you references apps. The app/site will serve as a private CDN for the apps.

Common code can be shared with a class library, sharing the same views accross web apps is unusual, you can factor out the commonality and retain the views for each application and reference the shared markup using helpers. You could also look at compiling the views in one project and share then between projects this way

Comment: I forgot to specify that there are views and controllers in the common project (login ResetPassword ...).

The controllers are recognized, but not Views.

Comment: common code can be shared with a class library, sharing the same views accross web apps is unusual, you can factor out the commonality and retain the views for each application and reference the shared markup using helpers. You could also look at compiling the views in one project and share then between projects this way.

Comment: Ok, for the views i can make a HtmlHelpers (like @Html.TextBoxFor for example) ?

Comment: The common views are identical, only the css is different.